# jQuery Error on Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site my browser crashes when viewing a web page, It says its my script on line 21 only Im unsure whats wrong? Can anybody see a problem?

```
jQuery.fn.carousel = function(previous, next, options){
    var sliderList = jQuery(this).children()[0];

    if (sliderList) {
        var increment = jQuery(sliderList).children().outerWidth("true"),
        elmnts = jQuery(sliderList).children(),
        numElmts = elmnts.length,
        sizeFirstElmnt = increment,
        shownInViewport = Math.round(jQuery(this).width() / sizeFirstElmnt),
        firstElementOnViewPort = 1,
        isAnimating = false;

        for (i = 0; i < shownInViewport; i++) {
            jQuery(sliderList).css('width',(numElmts+shownInViewport)*increment + increment + "px");
            jQuery(sliderList).append(jQuery(elmnts[i]).clone());
        }

        jQuery(previous).click(function(event){
            if (!isAnimating) {
                if (firstElementOnViewPort == 1) {
                    jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "-" + numElmts * sizeFirstElmnt + "px");
                    firstElementOnViewPort = numElmts;
                }
                else {
                    firstElementOnViewPort--;
                }

                jQuery(sliderList).animate({
                    left: "+=" + increment,
                    y: 0,
                    queue: true
                }, "swing", function(){isAnimating = false;});
                isAnimating = true;
            }

        });

        jQuery(next).click(function(event){
            if (!isAnimating) {
                if (firstElementOnViewPort > numElmts) {
                    firstElementOnViewPort = 2;
                    jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "0px");
                }
                else {
                    firstElementOnViewPort++;
                }
                jQuery(sliderList).animate({
                    left: "-=" + increment,
                    y: 0,
                    queue: true
                }, "swing", function(){isAnimating = false;});
                isAnimating = true;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

---

Line 21 is

```
jQuery(sliderList).append(jQuery(elmnts[i]).clone());
```

I call my plugin with...

```
$('.viewer').each(function() {
    $(this).carousel('.viewer .simplePrevious', '.viewer .simpleNext');
});
```

Comment: can you post your html and how you call the plugin?

Comment: can you tell us which is line 21? I'm assuming this isn't how the file starts

Comment: Ive amended my question @moopet

Comment: Im not receiving an error @Andy, My browser crashes until i force quit it

Comment: ok sounds like an infinite loop. so it works without that line 21? what value does `shownInViewport` have?

Answer (score -2):

Is it on an **HTML5 element** and in **IE**?
I have had a similar problem, even with html5shiv. had to revert to xhtml for it to work again.